# Fetch the data from twitter user timeline in node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am trying to fetch tweets of the logged in user from twitter in node.js but getting below error

{ errors: [ { code: 32, message: 'Could not authenticate you.' } ] }

Below is the snippet of my code,any help will be really appreciable

```
var oauthSignature =require('oauth-signature');
var request = require('request');
var timestamp =Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
function guid() {

    function s4() {
      return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + s4()  + s4()  +
    s4()  + s4() + s4() + s4();
}
var uuid = guid();
var options = {
    encodeSignature: true // will encode the signature following the RFC 3986 Spec by default 
}

var httpMethod = 'GET',
    url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json',
    parameters = {
        oauth_consumer_key : 'wxyrliZD8VdweAzzS31FElIkhK',
        oauth_token : '3724495214-DBOnDCGcWtsektrxb8o6N3eKsTnahvL7OjJDzAfS',
        oauth_nonce : uuid,
        oauth_timestamp : timestamp,
        oauth_signature_method : 'HMAC-SHA1',
        oauth_version : '1.0'
    },
    consumerSecret = 'MIQwmQveTqMsFBxoJTfx8Coh9ZQ41eaV0SgJsdGKquXWKThaCHv',
    tokenSecret = 'JBxBAgXxUVh3RZHE9ZXRTYbujYhD9ekrYiCee0hxsWA2U',
    // generates a RFC 3986 encoded, BASE64 encoded HMAC-SHA1 hash 
    encodedSignature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, url, parameters, consumerSecret, tokenSecret);
    var signature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, url, parameters, consumerSecret, tokenSecret,
        { encodeSignature: false});
    console.log(signature)
    // generates a BASE64 encode HMAC-SHA1 hash    

  request.get({url:'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json',
            'headers':{'Authorization':' OAuth oauth_token="3724495214-DBOnDCGcWtseketrxb8o6N3KsTnahvL7OjJDzAfS",oauth_signature='+encodeURI(signature)+',oauth_version="1.0",oauth_nonce='+uuid+', oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_consumer_key = "wxyrliZD8VdwAzrzS31FElIkhK", oauth_timestamp='+timestamp},json:true,timeout: 5000},function (e, r, user) {
              console.log(e,user);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to this.Please check below code.Instead of building custom code we can use node module 'twitter-node-client'

```
var Twitter =  require('twitter-node-client').Twitter;
var error = function (err, response, body) {
    console.log('ERROR [%s]', err);
};
var success = function (data) {
    console.log('Data [%s]', data);
};
var config = {
    "consumerKey": "key",
    "consumerSecret": "secret",
    "accessToken": req.session.twitterAccessToken,
    "accessTokenSecret": req.session.twitterAccessSecret    
};
var twitter = new Twitter(config);
twitter.getUserTimeline({user_id: req.session.influencer.twitterId,count: '1'}, error,success);
```